# Fedora 30: extreme inconsistency on connection speed

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, fedora, slow-connection

I upgraded from **Fedora 29 to 30**.

I'm facing a very annoying network issue on Fedora 30: **extreme inconsistency on connection speed!**

My internet connection is relatively fast: I can download files approximately `~10MB/s`. One example is Fedora 30 ISO (1.8G) in ~3 minutes.

```
wget https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/30/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-30-1.2.iso
```

If I run `speedtest-cli` this is what I get:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from COPEL Telecom (138.204.24.191)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by COPEL TELECOM (Curitiba) [10.42 km]: 8.223 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 102.58 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed....................................................................................................
Upload: 105.77 Mbit/s
```

Not bad at all. So far so good.

However, for the majority of the websites out there, I **can not even get 10% of that**... that's pretty strange. For the below links I'm getting something around `~100KB/s to ~300KB/s`. Yes, extremely slow!

Examples:

```
wget http://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/speedtest/1000mb.bin
wget https://github.com/torvalds/linux/archive/master.zip
wget https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/archive/master/inkscape-master.zip
```

1) I tested the very same links links on the other servers I have, and they downloaded even `+10MB/s`. Super fast. Links are good.
2) The incredible thing is that I live loaded Fedora's 27/28/29 and I could get the super fast result: `+10MB/s`. Super fast. My network board is working well. By the way, if it was not working well, the Fedora ISO described above would not download at `~10MB/s`.

Slow websites: `mirror.nl.leaseweb.net, github.com, gitlab.com`

- What could be the issue?
- Why few websites Fedora 30 downloads extremely fast and for other websites Fedora 30 is sooooo slow?

Comment: Roughly where are you in the world? That speedtest mirror is in Brazil. Fedora has mirrors globally, check which one you are being routed to.